# Is adding bots to an unlocked package supported?

Tags: salesforcedx, cicd, einstein-chatbot

Running into the following error trying to create an unlocked package for Bots:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package 0Ho3t000000PB6RCAW --installationkeybypass --wait 10 --json -v dev-hub-org
```

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "Error",
  "message": "Digital_Assistant: Not available for deploy for this organization",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "commandName": "PackageVersionCreateCommand",
  "stack": "Error: Digital_Assistant: Not available for deploy for this organization\n    at /Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/package/packageUtils.js:558:27\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (/Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/sfdxError.js:171:27)\n    at PackageVersionCreateCommand.catch (/Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/ToolbeltCommand.js:248:46)\n    at async PackageVersionCreateCommand._run (/Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:97:13)\n    at async Config.runCommand (/Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.81.0-7b953c80d1/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/config.js:173:24)\n    at async Main.run (/Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.81.0-7b953c80d1/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/main.js:27:9)\n    at async Main._run (/Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.81.0-7b953c80d1/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:43:20)\n    at async Object.run (/Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.81.0-7b953c80d1/dist/cli.js:32:20)",
  "warnings": []
}
```

Is adding bots to an unlocked package supported?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [metadata coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50), Bots can only be put in unnamespaced unlocked packages.